# Flutter: how to hide Cursor's "belly" on textfield

Tags: android, flutter, dart, cursor, textfield

Whenever the user clicks on textfield in order to change it, the cursor appears and so it's so-called "belly" (I don't what's it called actually, see picture below - red arrow). I want to enable interactive selection (i.e. enabling to move the cursor alongside the text field), and to show the blinking cursor on edit, but I want that so-called cursor's to not appear.

[image]

here is my code:

```dart
TextField(
    enableInteractiveSelection: true,
    showCursor: true,
    autofocus: false,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        isDense: true,
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))
        ),
    ),
    onChanged: (text) => {},
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    controller: _firstNameChanged
       ? (_firstNameController..text = _newFirstName)
       : (_firstNameController..text = userRep.firstName),
    inputFormatters: [
       FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[a-zA-Z]'))
    ],
    focusNode: _firstNameInputFocusNode,
    onSubmitted: (text) {
       if(text.isNotEmpty) {
          setState(() {
            _newFirstName = text;
            _firstNameChanged = true;
          });
       }
    },
    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
       fontSize: 16.0,
       color: Colors.black,
    )
)
```

Any ideas, please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65247744/how-to-remove-text-field-cursor-bubble-in-flutter/65248206#65248206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Dude comment, I was finally able to solve this according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65248206/13727011).

full code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
      textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.transparent, /// <- Added
      cursorColor: Colors.lightGreen[800],
      primaryColor: Colors.green,
      accentColor: Colors.lightGreen[800],
      fontFamily: 'NewRomanTimes',
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 72.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
      )
    ),
    home: MyHomePage()
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is probably outdated, as of 2022 this is how you change color to the handle and selection (you can use `Colors.transparent` to hide it alltogether) :

```
ThemeData().copyWith(
              textSelectionTheme: 
TextSelectionThemeData(
   selectionColor: Colors.yellow[900], 
   selectionHandleColor: Colors.yellow[900])
)
```