# how to remove text field cursor bubble in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

How to remove this bubble in flutter while typing in the text field. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
          selectionHandleColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: TextField())),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

TextField set `enableInteractiveSelection` property to false can resolve this issue.

```
 enableInteractiveSelection: true,
```

Comment: this parameter disable selection at all

Answer (score 4):

You will have to change the theme property to change the color of the cursor bubble.
In your theme change the **textSelectionHandleColor** to **transparent** . Like this.

```
Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.transparent, 
      ),
```